# Как открывать клавиатуру, привязанную к EditText, автоматически?

Tags: java, android, клавиатура, edittext

Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске активности или фрагмента, который имеет `EditText`, автоматически открывалась клавиатура, привязанная к этому `EditText`?

**MainActivity**:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        editText.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого у `EditText` нужно вызвать метод `requestFocus()`

`edit_text.requestFocus()`

Если не работает добавьте:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Не работает. (ещё три символа нужно (минимальная длина комментария - 15 символов))

Comment: @ИмяФамилия покажите код

Comment: Добавил код....

Comment: @ИмяФамилия запустил ваш код. все прекрасно работает

Comment: Проверил на телефоне и эмуляторе. Нигде не работает. На телефоне API 27, на эмуляторе - 30.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия добавьте         getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. А что делает этот метод?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

Нашел на просторах stackOverFlow такой код:

Создаете метод

```
private fun showSoftKeyboard(context: Context, editText: EditText) {
        try {
            editText.requestFocus()
            editText.postDelayed({
                val keyboard = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                keyboard.showSoftInput(editText, 0)
            }, 200)
        } catch (npe: NullPointerException) {
            Timber.e(npe)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }
    }
```

А в методе onCreate:

```
showSoftKeyboard(this, your_edit_text)
```